# Working of scanf and checking if input is int

Tags: c, int, scanf

I wanted to check whether input given is integer input or not. I did not wanted to store input in a string. After seeing several questions on stackoverflow and by hit and trial, I have created following code

```
while(scanf("%d%c",&num,&a) != 2 || a != '\n')
{
    printf("Please enter an integer only : ");
    if(a == '\n')
        scanf("%c",&a);
    else
    {
        while(a != '\n')
            scanf("%c",&a);
    }
}
```

It works but according to my understanding, the following should have also worked

```
while(scanf("%d%c",&num,&a) != 2 || a != '\n')
{
    printf("Please enter an integer only : ");
    while(a != '\n')
        scanf("%c",&a);
}
```

Can someone please tell me why above did not worked ?? Also if someone has better solution please give it also.

Note  :I am considering 12qwe also as an invalid input. I just want integers.

Comment: Maybe "%d%n" format is what you need. You could also check scanf()s return value.

Comment: I did what you told. But what it is doing is that it checks for the integer part correctly. But when integer is entered correctly, it skips next scanf() in my code. Do /n remains in buffer here ?? I think it should not.

Comment: No, I meant "%d%n". %n reports the number of succesfully consumed characters: in you case the number of numerical characters in the input string. After that, you could loop until you get a '\n'. (in fact you don;t need the %n; just read a %d, and than loop until '\n')

Comment: @屾顶洞人 张博 Second code hangs enter qwe as input twice. You will see it outputs "Enter an integer : " infinitely.

Comment: if I just read an integer and loop until /n, it will except 12qwe as a valid input (Not sure but I think it will). I don't want that. And earlier, I used %d/n by mistake. But now when you have told the use of %n, I think it will not fulfill the requirement in this case

Comment: First: specify what you *do* want to accept. Second: specify what you want to *consume* (or skip). For instance: if the input consists of "11 12 aa\n13\n", should the second call to the input function return 12, and the third an error, or should the first return 11, and the second return 13?

Comment: I want to accept only one integer value. In "11 12 aa\n13\n", I assume you entered "11 12 aa" pressed enter and then "13". Here it should give error in the first case as it contains characters which are not integers. In second case, it should accept 13 as it is an integer. So, first call would be error and ask user to enter again and second call should be accepted. If "11 12 aa\n13\n" is entered as it is (user is typing \n ), then also it should be an error. Only acceptable input from user is just an integer value. Nothing else, no spaces, no other characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with

```
while(scanf("%d%c",&num,&a) != 2 || a != '\n')
{
    printf("Please enter an integer only : ");
    while(a != '\n')
        scanf("%c",&a);
}
```

is that if `a` happens to contain `'\n'` before the scan, and the scan fails, the inner `while` loop doesn't run at all. So

- if the scan failed trying to parse an `int` from the input stream because the input was e.g. `"ab c\n"`, the offending input remains in the input stream, the next `scanf` in the outer `while` loop control fails parsing an `int` again, `a` remains `'\n'`, repeat.
- if an input error occurred before reading a character from the stream into `a`, the `scanf` in the outer loop control fails because of a corrupted stream, repeat.

In the other version,

```
while(scanf("%d%c",&num,&a) != 2 || a != '\n')
{
    printf("Please enter an integer only : ");
    if(a == '\n')
        scanf("%c",&a);
    else
    {
        while(a != '\n')
            scanf("%c",&a);
    }
}
```

you make at least some progress as long as there is input to be read from the stream, since whatever `a` contains, you read at least one character from the input stream before attempting the next parsing of an `int`. It will also result in an infinite loop if the input stream is corrupted/closed/ends prematurely, e.g. if you redirect stdin from an empty file. You can have that loop also output multiple `"Please enter an integer only : "` messages by giving input like `"a\nb\nc\nd\n".

So you should check whether `scanf` encountered the end of the stream or some other read error before converting anything from the input, and abort in that case:

```
int reads;
while(((reads = scanf("%d%c", &num, &a)) != 2 && reads != EOF) || a != '\n')
{
    printf("Please enter an integer only : ");
    // read at least one character until the next newline
    do {
        reads = scanf("%c", &a);
    }while(reads != EOF && a != '\n');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are saying. So if input is qwe\n, and %d%c is required, then can you please tell me what does scanf exactly do ??? I used to believe that it will read q from the input, determine it is not an integer and then for %c, assign w to a (variable). And then in inner while loop, it will read characters till \n.

Comment: With an input of `qwe\n`, `scanf("%d&c", &num, &a)` would fail to parse an `int` from the stream, so not store anything in either `num` or `a`, return 0, and leave `qwe\n` in the input stream. If a conversion fails, no subsequent conversions are attempted, and no input from the point of failure (inclusive) on is consumed.

Comment: Thanks man. I understood. I was completely wrong about how scanf works. I think now following code should also work if i initialize a to something in starting and after inner while loop in my code which was completely wrong previously. It is not as good as yours as it do not check if input is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong way to do. You can rather read the input using `fgets()` and then parse your string for integer ASCII range.

```
fgets(s, 1024, stdin)

for (i=0; s[i] ! = '\0';i++) {
if( s[i] <'0' && s[i] >'9')
  // not an integer<br>
```

You can also use standard functions like `isalnum`, `isalpha` etc.

Comment: I already mentioned I did not wanted to store input as a string

Answer (score 1):

it works……

```
while(scanf("%d%c",&num,&a) != 2 || a != '\n')
{
    printf("Please enter an integer only : ");
    do{
        scanf("%c",&a);
    }while(a != '\n');
}
```

Comment: Ya, you are right, it works. But I don't understand how. For eg, if I enter a and press enter, then my input is a\n and %d would consume a, \n will be consumed by the first %c in while loop. Then what goes in the scanf() of do while loop ??

Comment: Thanks for trying. It is better than my first solution but still the problem is the same. I don't understand how it works.