# Simple C Code Error

Tags: c, stack, malloc, free

Does anyone know why I am getting a segfault when I run this code? Valgrind tells me that I have "uninitialized value of size 4" on line 13 **if( !isdigit(x) )** and an invalid read size 2 on the same line -- address is not stack'd, malloc'd, or free'd.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int x;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if( !isdigit(x) )
    {
        printf("You entered %d\n", x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You did not enter a valid number!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `isdigit` is meant to be used against character values; it will return true for an input of `'1'` and false for an input of `'a'`, for example.  What are you entering for your input?

Comment: `isdigit()` isn't going to work in the way you are hoping if you use using `%d`. If you enter `1`, for instance, `x` will not contain the ASCII code for the character `1`, so `isdigit()` will return false.

Comment: Please remember to always check whether input succeeded: `scanf(...) == 1`?

Comment: Unrelated, but scanf will fail if the input is not a digit. So instead of checking, "isdigit" you can replace it with the result of scanf.

Comment: "getting a segfault" - it's not a segfault.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that if `scanf` will fail x will be uninitialized. 
It is better to enter data in a character array. Otherwise your code has no sense because you are unable to enter a non-number in an object of type int. Moreover if you enter a number the result of using function `isdigit` can be unexpected.

Comment: I don't think is the solution. Per example, if you initialize x with zero value, and you enter "dkj", the output is going to be You entered 0. That's not what he wants. Of course, it's always a good practice to initialize variable with a default value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your code with g++, resulting in no segfault.

Entering values of:

5, -1, 27, 43545gbb, and gggg

produced results:

5, -1, 27, 43545, and 1729208414

Comment: Your input causes undefined behaviour. You're not adhering to the preconditions of `isdigit`. Not to mention that it's clear from the last output that you're using an uninitialized variable. In short, while this doesn't segfault for you (now), it could at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    char a;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");

    while(scanf("%d%c",&x,&a) != 2 || a != '\n')
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer only : ");
        do
        {
            scanf("%c",&a);
        }while(a != '\n');
    }

    printf("You entered %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The code show you a complex way of how to use scanf. For more information : [Working of scanf and checking if input is int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049893/working-of-scanf-and-checking-if-input-is-int)

**According to the c documentation : isdigit**

Prototype:

```
int isdigit( int ch );
```

Parameters:

```
ch  -   character to classify
```

Purpose:

> Checks if the given character is a numeric character (0123456789).
>   The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as **unsigned char** and is not equal to EOF.

Return value:

> Non-zero value (true) if the character is a numeric character, 0 (false) otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

***Why the problem on Line 13?***.  Line 13 is `if( !isdigit(x) )`
You did not initialize x when you created it on line 8,
Therefore, if an unacceptable value is entered, and processed by `scanf()` on line 11, it will continue to be uninitialized by the time it gets to the `isdigit()` function.

The problem is that `isdigit()` expects The input must be a character with integer value between 0 and 255.  Any other value will lead to *undefined behavior*.  ***Segfaults are one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior.***

There are other ways to implement this, for example:
Here is an example using a char array (string).  Note the comments to explain why certain things were done.

```
int main()
{
    //int x;
    char x[2];  //Good for only one digit

    printf("Please enter an integer with up to 10 digits: ");
    //scanf("%d", &x); 
    scanf("%1s", x); //Edited to allow maximum field width of 1.

   // if( !isdigit(x) )        
    if( isdigit(x[0]) ) //note the "!" was removed for logic to work
    {
        printf("You entered %d\n", atoi(x)); //note use of atoi() to convert string to int.
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You did not enter a valid number!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `isdigit` takes `int`. It's just that the `int` you give it has to be in the range of `unsigned char`, or `EOF`.

Comment: Why read to string and convert, when you can check `if scanf(%d)==1` ?

Comment: @prajmus - yes, scanf() will work. But so will an array of char. Since isdigit() is a character tester, I thought it would be better to illustrate using that function with char types as an example. Besides, the core issue here is why the segfault? That is answered by addressing an illegal value being passed as an argument to isdigit.

Comment: `char x[2]; scanf("%s", x);` - no.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - edited with expanded buffer.  Let me know if that was not the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: @ryyker not really any better, it still has a buffer overflow. Use a maximum field width modifier in the scanf.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - Edited, thanks. Still learning variations of `scanf()` format specifiers. Appreciate the help.